# mysql_fetch_assoc() dies and gives error on random page loads?

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a page that contains a fair few database queries, each appended with `or die()`. I'm loading this page every 1 second for testing, and on random page loads (it could take two, it could take five, or ten) `die()` is switched and an error given.

**I broke down the script, and managed to isolate the particular offending query, which is:**

```
$fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) or die("Error 3:" . mysql_error());
```

**This particular line is contained within:**

```
if($size > 0) {
    $off_id = array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $off_id[] = $row['off_id'];
    }

    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($off_id);
    echo '</pre>';

    $rand = rand(0,$size);
    $off_id = $off_id[$rand];

    $query = "UPDATE rotation_data SET hit_counter = hit_counter + 1 WHERE off_id = '{$off_id}'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Error 1:" . mysql_error());

    $query = "SELECT * FROM offer_data WHERE off_id = '{$off_id}'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Error 2:" . mysql_error()); 
    $fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) or die("Error 3:" . mysql_error());
    $offer_url = $fetch['url']; $geo_target = $fetch['geo_target']; $blank = $fetch['blank'];

}
```

**Things I noticed:**

- No `mysql_error()` is returned/printed. Only `Error 3:` is.
- The `$off_id` array dumps correctly each and every time, so there's always an `$off_id` to be used in the previous `$result` query, and if there wasn't, that should trigger `die()` for the `$result` query instead.

I don't really understand why this would occur on random page loads, and not all the time, as this perhaps points to it not being a syntax issue, but a load issue?

However, even if it's a load issue, I don't understand why that particular query would fail and trigger a `die()` while the others are fine.

Any help in understanding why this might be, and suggestions of what I could do to fix this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [`or die()` must die](http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/or-die-must-die). Also, for statement errors, use `mysql_error($result)`

Comment: You shouldn't be using mysql anymore, use mysqli or PDO. http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqli.php

Comment: Props for the suggestion @Phil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that your query here returns no results:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM offer_data WHERE off_id = '{$off_id}'";
```

The following statement will not return `FALSE`, just an empty result set into `$result`.

```
// No results here this time...
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Error 2:" . mysql_error());
```

And then you attempt to fetch a row from an empty result resource.  This results in `FALSE` not because of error, but because there are no rows to fetch, and your short-circuit evaluation calls `die()`.

We cannot see where you are setting `$size`, but it's possible that you are occasionally reading past the array bounds of `$off_id` by reaching a random value that is larger than that array.

Comment: "We cannot see where you are setting $size, but it's possible that you are occasionally reading past the array bounds of $off_id by reaching a random value that is larger than that array." - That's what I'm about to test.

Comment: @Pixelatron No, it wouldn't `die()`. It just wouldn't update any rows because none would be matched, but the query would still have been successful.  It's only a fetch call where you'll see problems, since `mysql_fetch()` actually returns `FALSE` when there are no rows.

Comment: Props @Michael! `$size` had the value of 5 in this case, while the array keys went from 1 to 4, and 5 was being used as the upper boundary of `$rand = rand(0, $size)`, hence the occasional error!